# Can't find a valid termcap file

Tags: perl

I have used the following Perl setup for years...

```
use Term::Cap;
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
use POSIX;
 
my $TermIOs = new POSIX::Termios;
$TermIOs->getattr;
my $OSpeed = $TermIOs->getospeed;
my $terminal = Tgetent Term::Cap { TERM => undef, OSPEED => $OSpeed };
(${norm}, ${bold}, ${under}) = map { $terminal->Tputs($_,1) } qw/me md us/;
```

...which allows me to change printed terminal text, e.g.:-

```
print ("\nModels will be limited to ${bold}$ModelArch${norm} systems greater than or equal to ${bold}$ModelMinSpeed${norm}.\n");
```

...and it has always worked fine. But now I am in a situation where I need to change shells and activate a big environment with hundreds of variables and $PATH manipulation. Once I do that, the above code starts throwing out the following:-

```
Can't find a valid termcap file at ugeqstat.pl line 16.
```

I can do a "man termcap" before and after the environment change and the results are the same. My $TERM value has not changed either. Is there a dependable way to avoid a simple complication like this? I guess I need to switch to something like Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants), which may be less prone to this issue, but it would require a lot of tedious script updates.

Comment: Works for me on MacOS Big Sur (Perl 5.32) and Ubuntu 20.04 (Perl 5.30).

Comment: Do you have a file `/etc/termcap`?  Do you have a termcap file somewhere else that you specify in the environment with `export TERMCAP=/some/where/else/termcap` or equivalent?  If not, the error message is correct — you don't have a termcap file that Perl can find.  Did you change o/s versions or anything recently?

Comment: I am sure the error message is correct, but what makes it difficult to debug is that I cannot find a termcap before or after the environment change. And the script works before the environment change, but not after. I am actually changing environments on the same workstation, so the O/S factor is consistent. It sort of seems like Term::Cap is defaulting to something unknown (to me) in one environment, but not another. Is there a way to get Perl to print the termcap location that it does manage to find or use?

Comment: You could try 'strace -o /tmp/foo perl ugeqstat.pl' or similar to see all the system calls the script makes. Then look in foo for where it does write(2, "Can't find a valid termcap file...") and look at the lines just before that for stat() or open() system calls to see the pathname(s) it's been trying to access for the termcap file.

Comment: http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/general/gnl01-WorkingEnvironment/ar01s17.html